# Applying for Student Visa while living in Australia on Working Holiday Visa

Tags: visas, australia, study, work, working-holiday

I am currently in Australia on a Working Holiday visa which will expire on March 3rd, 2018. I will be applying for a Student Visa soon as I have received my CoE for Uni recently, but I've come to understand that you are not allowed to work until commencement of your course. I've applied for the second semester due to travelling when the first semester starts that had already been pre-arranged. So it's to my understanding that I am unable to work until July when my course begins.

Is there any way I can work while I am waiting? I'm already in Australia and it seems pointless to wait around for 4 months without work.

Comment: Go on a working holiday to New Zealand for 4 months